# Rapberry Pi 2 + Win 10 Core + C# + DHT22 or DS18B20 - Data Reading

Tags: c#, azure, sensors, raspberry-pi2, iot

Can anyone provide sample code or guide to read temperature sensor (DHT22 or DS18B20) data which is plugged on Rpi2. I would like to read data from c# library.

I am able to work with Touch & Motion sensor using c# script. I tried so many samples and my own code to read temperature sensor data but no luck for that.

Hope someone has try it before!

Answer (score 0):

I used the library from https://www.hackster.io/porrey/dht11-dht22-temperature-sensor-077790 to get readings from the dht22 and dht11. Those sensors are pretty picky. 
Then I got a BMP085 and was able to get reliable readings from it with samples for the I2C hookup. This was pretty easy and stable.
I don't think they have the low level stuff in place to use the DS18B20 in Windows yet (early dec 2015). Something about the timing for the one wire protocol used. I assume it will be added at some point.
So you probably want to grab the library from huckster.io and add that to your project right now.